# Synchronized does not work by cyclic barrier

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

```
public class Test {

    final int counter = 0; // it may be a different number
    int add = 0;

    public synchronized void testSync() throws InterruptedException {
        add++;
        if (add == counter) {
            add = 0;

            notifyAll();
        } else {
            while (add > 0) {

                wait();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

How can I fix the code to make it work?I need to make it work as a cyclic barrier.

Comment: Modify `add` after doing work, before the notify. Check the `add` immediately after the wait to decide if it's your turn to do work.

Comment: In this example, `add == counter` is never true.

Comment: In this example - yes, but  i wrote that "counter" can be a different positive number too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test {
    final int counter = 0; // it may be a different number
    final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(counter);

    public void testSync() throws InterruptedException, BrokenBarrierException {
        barrier.await();
    }
}
```